# Upload Custom VHD image to Azure Stack Market Place

Tags: windows, azure, linux-on-azure, azure-cli

I've uploaded a VHD image to blob storage and create a image from that and create VM from that successfully. But when creating new VM in Operating System Disk Image my image is not showing. I tried to add market place by,

```
 Add-AzureRMGalleryItem -SubscriptionId (Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName 'my subscription').SubscriptionId -GalleryItemUri https://ubuntuimage.blob.myurl/UbuntuImage.SimpleVMTemplate.16.4.0.azpkg -Apiversion "2015-04-01" –Verbose
```

When i run above code got below error. But i've installed Azure Stack tools for power shell already,

```
Add-AzureRMGalleryItem : The term 'Add-AzureRMGalleryItem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzureRMGalleryItem -SubscriptionId (Get-AzureRmSubscription -Subs ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-AzureRMGalleryItem:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm new to the azure. Please suggest me how to add image to Azure Stack market place?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Add-AzsGalleryItem from module "Azs.Gallery.Admin".